# Where can I find MySql 4.0.30 for windows?

Tags: mysql, windows-services

I need to adapt our testing server to our production one that is stored on Aruba.
Aruba use MySql 4.0.30 but I can't find them nowhere!
Anybody know where can I find it ? or anybody has the installer stored anywhere?

Davide

Comment: Support for all versions before mysql 5 has been discontinued. I dont see why Aruba will not run on the newer versions of mysql, as a matter of fact I've never had any problems with my webapps with I update mysql.

Comment: @Robin : Aruba is an italian hosting/housing provider!

Answer (score 2):

According to http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/210800 (an email from a MySQL employee) this is a non-public release for customers who are too inflexible to upgrade. It says you can pay for "extended support" to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Here for you source: http://mirror.provenscaling.com/mysql/community/source/4.0/mysql-4.0.30.tar.gz

Binaries only there for 4.1: http://mirror.provenscaling.com/mysql/community/binaries/4.1/

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not require much installation steps like most windows software.

Just copy the mysql dir and the mysql data dir from the production environment to your local machine and start mysqld.exe (does not need to be run as a service) from the bin directory with:

```
mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\path\to\my.ini" MySQL
```

If it does not start, you most likely tweak some path entries in your my.ini.

Or you can install the latest 4.x Server you find and replace the binaries and data files with the ones you get from production. That should totally do it.